# SVN - Eclipse Juno difficulty in opening existing workspace and not able to see branch name

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have opened my SVN project in Eclipse Juno which was checked out in Indigo...

I am able to view all files and everything ....but not able to check in/synchronize since **it is NOT showing any branch name in it.**

Answer (score 4):

The following steps worked for me.

Ensure your svn repository is set up correctly via the SVN Repository view.

1. Right click on the project in package explorer you want to connect to the repository.
2. Select the delete option. Do not select the checkbox to remove contents from the file system. (The project icon will remain in the package explorer but will look like a project closed icon.)
3. Now click on File>Import.
4. In the resulting popup select General>Existing Projects into Workspace, Select the project from the file system. It will now appear back in your package explorer with the svn icons showing that it is connected to the repository

The import action triggers eclipse into checking the .svn and activating the svn plugin. Just installing Juno and pointing the workspace at an existing project doesn't trigger that step.

Comment: +1 thanks for that trick, one should have hoped that eclipse would be smart enough to do this at its own...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not installed SVN into your Juno installation. Install it and restart and you will be fine.

Comment: Yes francis , i have already installed SVN... in file->new project- > i can see SVN -> which has projects from SVN option....

Comment: Does it show the icon in the package/project explorer indicating your files are under source control?

Comment: yes , my packages are shown in project explorer.... but branch details are not shown

Comment: But do the icons have the indication that they are in source control? It's possible there is a problem with the Eclipse SVN installation communicating with your SVN on the machine.

Comment: No icon is not showing the branch name at the right side of the modules (packages)

Comment: I just installed SVN from juno update site.... so that must be a problem.....is there any other way to install svn from any other site or something?     (or) else tell me how we should install SVN basically?

Comment: I have the same problem. Just installed the Subversive plugin from juno http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno using Install New Software and though the plugin shows that it's installed in the About box, I can't use it on my projects already synched with SVN.